# C++0x: Overload Resolution

Tags: c++11, overloading, initializer-list

In the Standard-Text there is an example in *8.5.4 (3) List-initialization [dcl.init.list]*

```
struct S {
    S(std::initializer_list<double>);  // #1
    S(const std::string&);             // #2
};
const S& r1 = { 1, 2, 3.0 };  // OK: invoke #1
const S& r2 { "Spinach" };    // OK: invoke #2 !!!
```

(the example is about the ref-to-temp, but I refer to the overload resolution here).

Whereas Scott Meyers in his talk/slides tells a different story:

> std::initializer_list parameters are always preferred over other types:

```
class Widget {
public:
    Widget(double value, double uncertainty);           // #1
    Widget(std::initializer_list<std::string> values);  // #2
};
double d1, d2;
Widget w1 { d1, d2 }; // tries to call #2; fails because
                      // no double ⇒ string conversion
```

The examples are slightly different, but aren't those about the same thing? When and how overload resolution with `initializer_list`-constructors happens? Or is there a different issue here?

**How is the overloading decided in both cases? If both are correct, what do I miss here?**

**Edit/Clarification** upon *Keric's* Comment: My feeling ist, that the two examples contradict each other:

- The Std gives an example where a `const char*` is converted to a `string`, which does not match the provided `initializer_list<int>` and therefore the provided "normal" `const string&`-c'tor is used.
- Scott's example initializes with `{double, double}` when an `intializer_list<int>`-c'tor is available and therefore chosen, because the list, he argues, is preferred. Thus the also provided `(double, double)`-c'tor is never chosen when initialized this way.

Of course, the Std is always right, but maybe I apply the example wrongly. The Std example has `&` in it, that I don't think are relevant for my question, but maybe I am wrong.

Scott's slides are quite recent, and I can not see that the relevant section(s) in the Std have changed to that respect (although, it's difficult to get everything into scope, because it's somewhat "widely spread" :-)

**Edit-2**: I got a mail from Scott himself that there was a [late change in the Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1151) that had not been incorporated into the slides.

Comment: If the standard is the most recent standard, then the standard is _correct_. What somebody (no matter how influential) puts on slides doesn't matter. If the standard actually says, in the language itself (examples are non-normative), then that's how it should work.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is, or which part of the examples you find unclear or contradictory. Could you please clarify? The old N3242 says (8.5.4(2)): "Initializer-list
constructors are favored over other constructors in list-initialization". I think this is pretty clear, non? (See also 13.3.3.1.5 for conversion to initializer list.)

Comment: Can a `const char[]` be converted to a `std::initializer_list<double>` (which is an array of `double`s, really)? I think the problem is that your constructor arguments still need to match, with or without implicit conversions.

Comment: surprisingly, gcc 4.5.1. fails the second initialization: http://www.ideone.com/Szbts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pursuant to N3291, the Working Draft from April 5, 2011, there has been a few changes to initializer lists, so Scott Meyer's slides may be from old data.

According to section 13.3.1.7 (so close to 1337):

> - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

So it does prefer initailizer lists. But if the initializer list doesn't match, then it will check the regular constructors to see if they match.

It goes on to say that if the initializer list is empty, then the default constructor is used.

Comment: Ok, you would say that Scott's example is not correct anymore? Because *"it will check the regular constructors"* then?

Comment: That's suprising, I would have thought non-initializer-list overloads were *more* specific. Then again if Foo({1,2,3}) uses initializer lists, it would be suprising if Foo({1,2}) *didn't*...

Comment: @spraff: not quite. If you place the `{...}` inside `(...)` you make the *init-list* explicit. With this you take control and both will be put to the *init-list* (I think). But if you leave out the outer `(...)` you get `Foo{1,2,3}` and `Foo{1,2}`. In both cases you let the compiler decide, and then the *init-list* is preferred. Same effect.

Comment: Putting them within `(...)` as in `({d1, d2})` for scott's example class will still use the non-initializer list constructor (because the init-list ctor won't match). However, not directly but using the copy constructor to create a temporary `Widget`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Although I had the corrected version of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1151 already, I was still confused by Scotts example. Thank you for pointing me to the correct paragraph.